# How can I view the "progress" of the solver in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I've got Matlab code that's trying to solve a system of 160 quadratics over 16 variables.  It's taking quite a while, and I was wondering if there was some way to "watch the computer work"?  If only to be more aesthetically pleasing than watching a blank command line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you are solving the system.  If you are using `fsolve`, then you can do something like this:

```
% Set options for the solver.
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter');

% Call the solver
[x,fval] = fsolve(@myfun,x0,options)
```

Try `help fsolve` for more display options.

Comment: I'm using solve rather than fsolve, and looking over the documentation it doesn't seem like solve has a similar object.  Do you know how one might do it using solve instead?

Comment: (If you hadn't noticed, I'm completely new to matlab.)

Comment: `fsolve` will only give you a numeric solution.  If you absolutely need a symbolic solution, as with `solve`, then perhaps something like Mathematica, Maple, or another symbolic math suite would give you more flexibility.

Comment: In general, yes.  But it will only give you a single solution.  The advantage of a symbolic solution is that you can "plug in" freely-chosen constants and get as many solutions as you need.